# Command delay when sending commands from DJI OSDK to DJI Matrice 100 via the serial

Tags: c++, delay, dji-sdk

I'm trying to control the Matrice 100 with OSDK. I have a RPi3 on the M100 that is suppose to control the the position using roll/pitch/z-vel/yawrate commands while localizing with GPS, camera and lidar.

My problem is that when I send a command from OSDK on the RPi3 I have a delay of 60-80 ms from the command is sent via the serial line till there is a response from the M100. I am checking the reponse time by logging the roll/pitch/yaw angles at 100Hz from the M100. From the logged data I can see that from the time I send a command till there is a significant change in angles (I try to do steps of 10 deg.) there is a delay.

A delay of up to 80 ms is way to large to do proper closed loop control of a drone.

From https://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/introduction/onboard-sdk-introduction.html
i gather that low-level-control should be possible at 200Hz on the M100 with OSDK which makes no sense if there is a 80 ms delay.

I have based my code on the sample code from DJI OSDK changing the close loop control to my own controller. Put the setup and way of sending commands is the same.

Thanks for any inputs that can help fix this or shed light on what the problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

OK first of all having 80 ms is not that bad if you are flying inside vicon room and use RPI as vicon based feed back controller from wifi. 80 ms is acceptable. In PID loop, just give a higher predictive gain.

Secondly, for visual/visualinerial/lidar/lidarinertical based navigation, I wont use RPI as RPI can not process those data in realtime. For example. to proceess VINSMONO you need at least TX2 grade CPU to process it at 10 hz with 100 feature points without loop closure.  We are talking about proccessing delay of 100ms. Still, it is controllable with correct amount of PID. This method can be seen from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1AbfRENy3OQ&t=4s

Third, if you are using it for trajectory control. Man, you are way out of your field. Trajectory control need feedback in terms of 100 hz and need controllable processing speed in terms of popular method such as A star, Dstar algorithm. This is not what RPI are designed to do.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. If i have localization at say 10 Hz what kind of control would you recommend using if there still is a 80 ms delay?
Would that be something like model predictive control?

Comment: you can try with MPC. but as far as i know. MPC from ETH group use much higher freuqnecy for input. I wound not suggest you to try that. Last time I fly with that MPC package, I had really bad crash.     with 10 HZ, i would recommend you to try only simple PID based waypoint navigation. That pretty much top you can do.  To even work on the PID based trajectory control, you need to fuse 10hz feedback with IMU, to get higher feedback rate.  for the PID control, you can stard with only PD. set the D accordinly with the 80 ms delay. You should get it working just fine.